# Displaying image outside of web root not working , why?

Tags: php, apache

I just learned about ["how to add image outside of web root"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402572/how-to-echo-image-that-is-outside-of-the-public-folder). I have done everything as mentioned. But the image is not displaying. Here's the code in the file called `get_image.php`. and the Directory structure:

`home.php`

```
`...
<body>
   <img src="/get_image.php?image=myimg.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</body
...`
```

I have checked `is_readable()` and `file_exists()` seems ok.

```
app
  |_upload_dir
      |_myimg.jpg
      |_ myimg2.png
Public_html
  |_asset_dir
  |_get_image.php
  |_ home.php
```

`get_image.php`

```
<?php
  $mime_type = mime_content_type("../app/upload_dir/{$_GET['image']}");
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);

  readfile("../app/upload_dir/{$_GET['image']}");
?>
```

So why the image is not displaying??

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error . Just a broken image :(  @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: show error log or turn on error display https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: And the images in `upload_dir` are permanent? That's not the temp dir for current uploads?

Comment: `upload_dir` is permanent @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: What is `var_dump(mime_content_type("../app/upload_dir/{$_GET['image']}"));` without setting headers and via direct request from address bar? Is this your own (local) server or a webhost?

Comment: `46:string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)` @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: Sorry that was not the error @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: Just observing the broken image does not suffice as research. Where's the `wget -S` and hexdump or `file -k -l` probe debugging?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved :) . Well... I forgot to `include` a file that had the `IMAGE_PATH` constant which was holding the path to the upload_dir.